# Catching intent with same URL and in one App

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making android app that needs to catch url of shared website in website. For example, you are running chrome, click share, choose your app, it opens and manage that link. I've wrote following code:

Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_login">
    <intent-filter android:label="Hello">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
String action = intent.getAction();
String type = intent.getType();

if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type.equals("text/plain")) {
   // ..do something
}
```

But occurred two problems:

1. Intent got caught only one time. When I share website it works great, but when I get back to browser and want to share again (same url or something else) intent doesn't get caught.
2. If I start app manually, then open website and share some link, another instance of app starts (not even app, but this specific activity).

Any advises how to resolve these problems?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I've solved first one, was pretty stupid mistake to be honest. I've put code fragment with getIntent in onCreate, should be in onResume. Anyway, still creates new instance of app when I've manually started the first one :(

EDIT: Putting

```
      android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

in manifest and moving code from onResume to

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    catchIntent(intent);
}
```

Solved problem. You have to remember to make another call in onCreate too so first catch can be triggered. It's good to add

```
  intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

as well.